# How to merge similar name to be come one name based on id, and Addition and substraction based on code

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I'm newbie, please dont give me minus score

I've data frame like this

```
    Month   Name       id   Info   d/k Ex/Im    Income
0   Jan    Alice sal  212  charge  k   export     100
1   Jan    sal Alice  212  charge  k   export      10
2   Jan    Bob        567  charge  k   export     200
3   Feb    Alice sal  212  charge  k   export     100
4   Jan    Bob        567  cost    k   import      75
5   jan    Bob        567  charge  D   export      50
```

In this case

I want to merge the name 'alice sal' and 'sal alice' (read first row name) to become one name because both of them has same ID. In this case "alice sal"

Then i want to make a conditional statement based by "debit(d (-) ) /credit(k (+) )" if there's a name with "D" indicator
So in this case "bob = 200-50 =150".

**Expected**

```
       Month      Feb      Jan
       Ex/Im      export  export      import
       Info        charge charge       cost 
ID.    Name
212    Alice sal     100    110           0
567    Bob             0    150          75
```

What should i do? This is my last code

```
df.pivot_table(index="Name", columns=["Month", "Ex/Im", "Info"], values="Income", aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
```

thanks for @ch33hau for your help,
the answer is

```
    # 1. Negate the values of `Income` when `D` is found, 
#    you can write your own method and use `df.apply` 
#    to make it idempotent if you prefer.
df.loc[df['d/k'] == 'D', 'Income'] = -df[df['d/k'] == 'D']['Income']

# 2. Group by
gdf = df.groupby(['id', 'Month', 'Ex/Im', 'Info']).agg({'Income':'sum', 'Name':'first'})

# 3. Lastly apply `pivot_table` which is quite similar to what you have wrote. 
gdf.pivot_table(
    index=["id", "Name"], 
    columns=["Month", "Ex/Im", "Info"], 
    values=["Name", "Income"], 
    aggfunc='sum', 
    fill_value=0)
```

it works  but comparison failed. This is the notice "futurewarning:element wise comparison= failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison ( result = method(y))

**i'll give more details**

```
        Month   Name       id   Info   d/k Ex/Im    Income
0        Jan    Alice sal  212  charge  K   export     100
1        Jan    Alice sal  212  charge  K   export      10
2        Jan    sal alice  212  charge  D   export     100
2        Jan    Alice sal  212  charge  D   export     100
4        Jan    Alice sal  212  cost    K   export     200
5        Jan    sal alice  212  cost    D   export      10
6        Jan    sal alice  212  cost    D   export      20
7        Feb    Alice sal  212  charge  k   export     100
```

based on id the result will

```
                  Income
  Month           Feb         Jan
  Ex/Im           export      export    import
  Info            charge      charge    cost
  id    Name            
  212   Alice sal 100         -90       170
```

note:
on my data frame, not only alice sal has similar name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# Preparing data
# Note that I have clean up the `jan` to `Jan` and `Charge` to `charge`
data = [{'Month': 'Jan', 'Name': 'Alice sal', 'id': 212, 'Info': 'charge', 'd/k': 'k', 'Ex/Im': 'export', 'Income': 100.15},
{'Month': 'Jan', 'Name': 'sal Alice', 'id': 212, 'Info': 'charge', 'd/k': 'k', 'Ex/Im': 'export', 'Income': 10},
{'Month': 'Jan', 'Name': 'Bob', 'id': 567, 'Info': 'charge', 'd/k': 'k', 'Ex/Im': 'export', 'Income': 200},
{'Month': 'Feb', 'Name': 'Alice sal', 'id': 212, 'Info': 'charge', 'd/k': 'k', 'Ex/Im': 'export', 'Income': 100},
{'Month': 'Jan', 'Name': 'Bob', 'id': 567, 'Info': 'cost', 'd/k': 'k', 'Ex/Im': 'import', 'Income': 75},
{'Month': 'Jan', 'Name': 'Bob', 'id': 567, 'Info': 'charge', 'd/k': 'D', 'Ex/Im': 'export', 'Income': 50}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```py
# Clean up name by ID
# Create a dataframe to store names depends on whichever found first.
df_name = df.groupby('id').first()[['Name']]

def cleanup_name(row, df_name):
    return df_name.at[row['id'], 'Name']

# `apply` is useful in applying complex logic, but it comes with some performance cost.
df['Name'] = df.apply(lambda x: cleanup_name(x, df_name), axis=1)
```

```py
# 1. Negate the values of `Income` when `D` is found, 
#    you can write your own method and use `df.apply` 
#    to make it idempotent if you prefer.
df.loc[df['d/k'] == 'D', 'Income'] = -df[df['d/k'] == 'D']['Income']

# 2. Group by
gdf = df.groupby(['id', 'Month', 'Ex/Im', 'Info']).agg({'Income':'sum', 'Name':'first'})

# 3. Lastly apply `pivot_table` which is quite similar to what you have wrote. 
gdf.pivot_table(
    index=["id", "Name"], 
    columns=["Month", "Ex/Im", "Info"], 
    values=["Name", "Income"], 
    aggfunc='sum', 
    fill_value=0)


# Result:
#                 Income
# Month           Feb         Jan
# Ex/Im           export      export    import
# Info            charge      charge    cost
# id    Name            
# 212   Alice sal 100         110       0
# 567   Bob       0           150       75
```

But you have to clean up your data first, there is one `jan` in `Month` where the rest start with an uppercase. Same for `Info`, one starts with uppercase.

#### Update:

After clean up the name, everything wrote before works good for me, by below data:

```py
data = [
    {'Month': 'Jan', 'Name': 'Alice sal', 'id': 212, 'Info': 'charge', 'd/k': 'K', 'Ex/Im': 'export', 'Income': 100},
    {'Month': 'Jan', 'Name': 'Alice sal', 'id': 212, 'Info': 'charge', 'd/k': 'K', 'Ex/Im': 'export', 'Income': 10},
    {'Month': 'Jan', 'Name': 'Alice sal', 'id': 212, 'Info': 'charge', 'd/k': 'D', 'Ex/Im': 'export', 'Income': 100},
    {'Month': 'Jan', 'Name': 'Alice sal', 'id': 212, 'Info': 'charge', 'd/k': 'D', 'Ex/Im': 'export', 'Income': 100},
    {'Month': 'Jan', 'Name': 'Alice sal', 'id': 212, 'Info': 'cost', 'd/k': 'K', 'Ex/Im': 'export', 'Income': 200},
    {'Month': 'Jan', 'Name': 'Alice sal', 'id': 212, 'Info': 'cost', 'd/k': 'D', 'Ex/Im': 'export', 'Income': 10},
    {'Month': 'Jan', 'Name': 'Alice sal', 'id': 212, 'Info': 'cost', 'd/k': 'D', 'Ex/Im': 'export', 'Income': 20},
    {'Month': 'Feb', 'Name': 'Alice sal', 'id': 212, 'Info': 'charge', 'd/k': 'K', 'Ex/Im': 'export', 'Income': 100}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

It will be great if you will prepare this kind of code to generate data next time when you raise a question, it will shorten the time to get a right answer =)

Comment: thanks sir, but comparison failed. This is the notice "futurewarning:element wise comparison= failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison ( result = method(y)) so my export file: row 1 alice sal 100 110, row 2 sal alice 0 0

Comment: It will be great if you can provide more details, even better if you can add your sample data in that can fits into `pd.DataFrame()`, so that we can all in the same page. The logic is more or less the same, I think what makes the differences might be data types, or the values, I will update my answer to put my sample data anyway.

Comment: oke sir, i edited my quiestion. thanks a lot, regards from indonesian @ch33hau

Comment: If the names will be more complex, it would be great to apply an additional method to clean up, I will add the step of clean up name. Also, it is good to provide not just data, but the code to populate data, which I will add as well for your new data, but it is really really good if you will provide when you raise a question in SO. Last thing, there should be no "import" in your new expected result.

Comment: How’s the solution to clean up?

Comment: I added it in the second part of those code, starts with `# Clean up name by ID`, sorry for didn't make it clear =P

Comment: Thanks a lot sir @ch33hau

Comment: sir, i need your help. im in trouble in your code, this is the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267872/negate-the-values-based-on-indicator

Comment: I added an answer there, it seems ok but the data doesn't looks right, and the negate part is case sensitive.